# Exception Error while reading from Azure Key Vault

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

We faced the below exception while trying to read a secret from Azure Key Vault from Service fabric application.

The application uses Client Certificate to authenticate with AAD and access the KeyVault to fetch the secret.

This issue is occurring intermittently.

Is there a way we could identify the root cause so that the same error can be prevented from further occurrences.

```
Message: AADSTS70002: Error validating credentials. AADSTS50012: Client assertion is not within its valid time range. 
Trace ID: 333ee9c1-c74f-432d-824a-000f38a0e400 
Correlation ID: 35b5cadf-c538-4f75-b1fb-56c4743088f4 
Timestamp: 2018-10-24 06:23:30Z
```

......

Comment: Any process now? If you still have any problem, please feel free to let me know.

Answer (score 0):

> Client assertion is not within its valid time range.

According to your error message and your issue occurs intermittently, I think it may be your **token's region time cause the problem**. Region time may have some time interval with your token valid time.

So, I suggest that you could use `DateTime.UtcNow` as standard to set your token start time and end time. Here is a code sample you could refer to.

```
private static async Task<string> GetClientAssertiotokenAsync(string tenantId,string clientId)
{
    X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(@"D:\Joey\Documents\joey.pfx", "password", X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);
    var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
    var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
    {
        Audience = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/token",
        Issuer = clientId,
        NotBefore = now.AddHours(1),
        Expires = now.AddHours(3),
        Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new[] {
        new Claim("sub",clientId)}),
        SigningCredentials = new X509SigningCredentials(cert)
    };
    SecurityToken token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
    string tokenString = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
}
```

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://github.com/TomSunGit/AzureADDemo).

Comment: Thank you for the response but I have a question. if the issue is with token’s region time then why are we seeing issue intermittently?                 
We are not doing authentication based on jwt security token handler. 
we are using client SDK Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory  
 
Thanks

Comment: When you region time match with your local time, it will work and when the region time no intersection, it will get issue. Could you provide me more your code to analyse your problem.